# 3rd party XML parser (xpath.js) gives error "Uncaught end tag name: div is not match the current start tagName"

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xpath, parse-platform

Using parse.com's cloud code, I'm trying to scrape data off a webpage to send to my iOS app. I have already implemented the web scraping code natively in iOS, but I'm trying to move this task to the backend.  I'm using a node.js library called [xpath.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath)

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {   


        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: "http://menu.ha.ucla.edu/foodpro/default.asp",
      success: function(httpResponse) {
        var text = httpResponse.text;
        var xpath = require("cloud/xpath.js"), dom = require("cloud/dom-parser.js").DOMParser;
        var doc = new dom().parseFromString(text);
        var cells = xpath.select("//td[starts-with(@class, 'menugridcell')]", doc);

        response.success("test " + cells.count);
        var listNode = xpath.select("//ul", cells[0])[0]; 
         },
     error: function(httpResponse) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
      }
});
});
```

However, when I run the code, I receive this error:

```
"Uncaught end tag name: div is not match the current start tagName:script"
```

Like I mentioned earlier, I have been able to successfully scrape the web data with a separate objective-c library, so the tags are consistent and the problem can't lie within the source code.

For the source code, here is the [webpage I'm scraping](http://menu.ha.ucla.edu/foodpro/default.asp). StackOverflow won't let me link directly to the source code, otherwise I'd give a direct link.

EDIT:

Here is the code in dom-parser.js

```
function DOMParser(options){
    this.options = options ||{locator:{}};

}
DOMParser.prototype.parseFromString = function(source,mimeType){    
    var options = this.options;
    var sax =  new XMLReader();
    var domBuilder = options.domBuilder || new DOMHandler();//contentHandler and LexicalHandler
    var errorHandler = options.errorHandler;
    var locator = options.locator;
    var defaultNSMap = options.xmlns||{};
    var entityMap = {'lt':'<','gt':'>','amp':'&','quot':'"','apos':"'"}
    if(locator){
        domBuilder.setDocumentLocator(locator)
    }

    sax.errorHandler = buildErrorHandler(errorHandler,domBuilder,locator);
    sax.domBuilder = options.domBuilder || domBuilder;
    if(/\/x?html?$/.test(mimeType)){
        entityMap.nbsp = '\xa0';
        entityMap.copy = '\xa9';
        defaultNSMap['']= 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
    }
    if(source){
        sax.parse(source,defaultNSMap,entityMap);
    }else{
        sax.errorHandler.error("invalid document source");
    }
    return domBuilder.document;
}
function buildErrorHandler(errorImpl,domBuilder,locator){
    if(!errorImpl){
        if(domBuilder instanceof DOMHandler){
            return domBuilder;
        }
        errorImpl = domBuilder ;
    }
    var errorHandler = {}
    var isCallback = errorImpl instanceof Function;
    locator = locator||{}
    function build(key){
        var fn = errorImpl[key];
        if(!fn){
            if(isCallback){
                fn = errorImpl.length == 2?function(msg){errorImpl(key,msg)}:errorImpl;
            }else{
                var i=arguments.length;
                while(--i){
                    if(fn = errorImpl[arguments[i]]){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        errorHandler[key] = fn && function(msg){
            fn(msg+_locator(locator));
        }||function(){};
    }
    build('warning','warn');
    build('error','warn','warning');
    build('fatalError','warn','warning','error');
    return errorHandler;
}
/**
 * +ContentHandler+ErrorHandler
 * +LexicalHandler+EntityResolver2
 * -DeclHandler-DTDHandler 
 * 
 * DefaultHandler:EntityResolver, DTDHandler, ContentHandler, ErrorHandler
 * DefaultHandler2:DefaultHandler,LexicalHandler, DeclHandler, EntityResolver2
 * @link http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html
 */
function DOMHandler() {
    this.cdata = false;
}
function position(locator,node){
    node.lineNumber = locator.lineNumber;
    node.columnNumber = locator.columnNumber;
}
/**
 * @see org.xml.sax.ContentHandler#startDocument
 * @link http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html
 */ 
DOMHandler.prototype = {
    startDocument : function() {
        this.document = new DOMImplementation().createDocument(null, null, null);
        if (this.locator) {
            this.document.documentURI = this.locator.systemId;
        }
    },
    startElement:function(namespaceURI, localName, qName, attrs) {
        var doc = this.document;
        var el = doc.createElementNS(namespaceURI, qName||localName);
        var len = attrs.length;
        appendElement(this, el);
        this.currentElement = el;

        this.locator && position(this.locator,el)
        for (var i = 0 ; i < len; i++) {
            var namespaceURI = attrs.getURI(i);
            var value = attrs.getValue(i);
            var qName = attrs.getQName(i);
            var attr = doc.createAttributeNS(namespaceURI, qName);
            if( attr.getOffset){
                position(attr.getOffset(1),attr)
            }
            attr.value = attr.nodeValue = value;
            el.setAttributeNode(attr)
        }
    },
    endElement:function(namespaceURI, localName, qName) {
        var current = this.currentElement
        var tagName = current.tagName;
        this.currentElement = current.parentNode;
    },
    startPrefixMapping:function(prefix, uri) {
    },
    endPrefixMapping:function(prefix) {
    },
    processingInstruction:function(target, data) {
        var ins = this.document.createProcessingInstruction(target, data);
        this.locator && position(this.locator,ins)
        appendElement(this, ins);
    },
    ignorableWhitespace:function(ch, start, length) {
    },
    characters:function(chars, start, length) {
        chars = _toString.apply(this,arguments)
        //console.log(chars)
        if(this.currentElement && chars){
            if (this.cdata) {
                var charNode = this.document.createCDATASection(chars);
                this.currentElement.appendChild(charNode);
            } else {
                var charNode = this.document.createTextNode(chars);
                this.currentElement.appendChild(charNode);
            }
            this.locator && position(this.locator,charNode)
        }
    },
    skippedEntity:function(name) {
    },
    endDocument:function() {
        this.document.normalize();
    },
    setDocumentLocator:function (locator) {
        if(this.locator = locator){// && !('lineNumber' in locator)){
            locator.lineNumber = 0;
        }
    },
    //LexicalHandler
    comment:function(chars, start, length) {
        chars = _toString.apply(this,arguments)
        var comm = this.document.createComment(chars);
        this.locator && position(this.locator,comm)
        appendElement(this, comm);
    },

    startCDATA:function() {
        //used in characters() methods
        this.cdata = true;
    },
    endCDATA:function() {
        this.cdata = false;
    },

    startDTD:function(name, publicId, systemId) {
        var impl = this.document.implementation;
        if (impl && impl.createDocumentType) {
            var dt = impl.createDocumentType(name, publicId, systemId);
            this.locator && position(this.locator,dt)
            appendElement(this, dt);
        }
    },
    /**
     * @see org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler
     * @link http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html
     */
    warning:function(error) {
        console.warn(error,_locator(this.locator));
    },
    error:function(error) {
        console.error(error,_locator(this.locator));
    },
    fatalError:function(error) {
        console.error(error,_locator(this.locator));
        throw error;
    }
}
function _locator(l){
    if(l){
        return '\n@'+(l.systemId ||'')+'#[line:'+l.lineNumber+',col:'+l.columnNumber+']'
    }
}
function _toString(chars,start,length){
    if(typeof chars == 'string'){
        return chars.substr(start,length)
    }else{//java sax connect width xmldom on rhino(what about: "? && !(chars instanceof String)")
        if(chars.length >= start+length || start){
            return new java.lang.String(chars,start,length)+'';
        }
        return chars;
    }
}

/*
 * @link http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ext/LexicalHandler.html
 * used method of org.xml.sax.ext.LexicalHandler:
 *  #comment(chars, start, length)
 *  #startCDATA()
 *  #endCDATA()
 *  #startDTD(name, publicId, systemId)
 *
 *
 * IGNORED method of org.xml.sax.ext.LexicalHandler:
 *  #endDTD()
 *  #startEntity(name)
 *  #endEntity(name)
 *
 *
 * @link http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ext/DeclHandler.html
 * IGNORED method of org.xml.sax.ext.DeclHandler
 *  #attributeDecl(eName, aName, type, mode, value)
 *  #elementDecl(name, model)
 *  #externalEntityDecl(name, publicId, systemId)
 *  #internalEntityDecl(name, value)
 * @link http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ext/EntityResolver2.html
 * IGNORED method of org.xml.sax.EntityResolver2
 *  #resolveEntity(String name,String publicId,String baseURI,String systemId)
 *  #resolveEntity(publicId, systemId)
 *  #getExternalSubset(name, baseURI)
 * @link http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/DTDHandler.html
 * IGNORED method of org.xml.sax.DTDHandler
 *  #notationDecl(name, publicId, systemId) {};
 *  #unparsedEntityDecl(name, publicId, systemId, notationName) {};
 */
"endDTD,startEntity,endEntity,attributeDecl,elementDecl,externalEntityDecl,internalEntityDecl,resolveEntity,getExternalSubset,notationDecl,unparsedEntityDecl".replace(/\w+/g,function(key){
    DOMHandler.prototype[key] = function(){return null}
})

/* Private static helpers treated below as private instance methods, so don't need to add these to the public API; we might use a Relator to also get rid of non-standard public properties */
function appendElement (hander,node) {
    if (!hander.currentElement) {
        hander.document.appendChild(node);
    } else {
        hander.currentElement.appendChild(node);
    }
}//appendChild and setAttributeNS are preformance key

if(typeof require == 'function'){
    var XMLReader = require('cloud/sax').XMLReader;
    var DOMImplementation = exports.DOMImplementation = require('cloud/dom').DOMImplementation;
    exports.XMLSerializer = require('cloud/dom').XMLSerializer ;
    exports.DOMParser = DOMParser;
}
```

Comment: What library is `cloud/dom-parser.js` in this case? It is probably parsing as XML instead of as HTML. What if you do `.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');`?

Comment: No -- same error.  I'm not sure what library dom-parser.js is, but I added the code from the file into the question

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demo this problem?

Comment: @BenSmith how is he supposed to create jsfiddle for a Node.js app?

Comment: Perhaps the website returns different output to the browser and Parse. This could happen because the website may try to optimize for specific browsers. Try outputting the value of  httpResponse.text somewhere and examine it manually. You may see that it does have malformed XML.

Answer (score 0):

the given page contains some XML tags in an html script. The opening tags may be ignored because they contains excaped qoutation marks. The parser finds the `</div>` (in a string in the script) and tries to fit it with the opening `<script>` and fails. You parser tries to read XML and didn't know the xhtml script area is CData.

You have to tell the parse to ignore (or read as CData) the script tag. Sorry but i didn't know how to do.

best regards Majo